# Creating custom school schedule

Tags: formatting, enumitem

I am trying to create a custom school schedule. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry,microtype,ulem}
\usepackage[pages=some]{background}
\usepackage{enumitem}


\begin{document}

\BgThispage

\begin{center}

\textbf{\Huge My title}

\end{center} 

\vspace{1cm}

{\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\textbf{\Large \uline{Monday -- Wednesday -- Friday}}}

\begin{itemize}[label={}]
\item[hour1] activity 1 
\item[hour2] activity 2
\item[hour3] activity 3

\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

The problems are the following: (1) I don't want to intent the paragraph in which days present;(2) i don't know how to **increase** the space between 'hour' and 'activity' and also, how to **decrease** the space between two activities; (3) i don't know how to remove page numbering.

I would appreciate any help :)

Comment: Sorry, but this is not minimal. I just tried to compile it and got stuck in font and polyglossia issues.

Comment: i just edited my MWE

Comment: Your problem is most certainly unrelated to any choice of font or language. If you remove these things completely, you will increase the number of people who is able to try your MWE. Same for the background picture, which we of course don't have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not the `day` - line being indented (it isn't!), but the item labels are shifted into the left margin.

Use the `wide` option and `labelindent=0pt` and  `labelsep=30pt` to align the labels left (indent)  -- the `labelsep` value changes the spacing between the labels and the activity here.

For more conveniency I suggest to use a special `\newlist` command for such lists!

The page number can be removed with `\pagestyle{empty}` (until another pagestyle will be used)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry,microtype,ulem}
\usepackage[pages=some]{background}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\backgroundsetup{
scale=1,
color=black,
opacity=0.4,
angle=0,
contents={%
  \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{ente}
  }%
}

\usepackage{unicode-math,xgreek}
%\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
%\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Libertine O} 

%\usepackage{polyglossia}
%\setdefaultlanguage{english}

\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\BgThispage

\begin{center}

\textbf{\Huge My title}

\end{center} 

\pagestyle{empty}

\vspace{1cm}

{%
  \setlength{\parindent}{0em}%
  \textbf{\Large\uline{Monday -- Wednesday -- Friday}}%
}

\begin{itemize}[label={},wide,labelindent=0pt,labelsep=30pt]
\item[hour1] activity 1 
\item[hour2] activity 2
\item[hour3] activity 3

\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are easier ways to achieve what you want. First of all, the titles can be done using `\section, \subsection`, and so on. With some customization, that can be done easily. Also, your "paragraph title" was not indented, rather the list items were not properly aligned with the left margin.

The space between item labels and content can be increased using `labelsep`, while the space between items is changed with `itemsep`. The page numbering is removed with `\pagestyle{empty}`.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{microtype,ulem}

\usepackage{unicode-math,xgreek}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Libertine O} 

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\pagestyle{empty}

\titleformat*{\section}{\centering\Huge\bfseries}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\Large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{\underline}

\begin{document}
\section*{My title}
\subsection*{Monday — Wednesday — Friday}

\begin{enumerate}[align=left, leftmargin=*, itemsep=-1mm, labelsep=1cm]
\item[hour1] activity 1 
\item[hour2] activity 2
\item[hour3] activity 3
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can autoamte the list with an `enumerate environment` and set the convenient keys from `enumitem`::
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{geometry,microtype,ulem}
    \usepackage[pages=some]{background}
    \usepackage{enumitem}

```
\backgroundsetup{
scale=1,
color=black,
opacity=0.4,
angle=0,
contents={%
  \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{cahier}
  }%
}

\usepackage{unicode-math,xgreek}%

 \defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Libertine O}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=modern]{greek}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\BgThispage

\begin{center}

\textbf{\Huge Τίτλος μου}

\end{center}

\vspace{1cm}

\noindent
\textbf{\Large \uline{Δευτέρα -- Τετάρτη -- Παρασκευή}}

\begin{enumerate}[label={Ώρα\arabic*}, wide = 0pt, labelsep=4em, noitemsep]
\item δραστηριότητα 1
\item δραστηριότητα 2
\item δραστηριότητα 3

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]